# Launching a Shell Script using a Global Shortcut on OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have a shell script, which I launch several times during work everyday. I do this by launching terminal, and launching the script from within. However, I would like to be able to launch it (from within a terminal) with a global OSX keyboard shortcut (Cmd+Shift+R say).

There are quite a few applications which work in this manner already (for eg. EverNote, RemindMeLater, even the default Cmd-Space which brings up the search utility) and hence, I am guessing this should be at least theoretically possible.

Could someone please tell me if and how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a global shortcut key, maybe try creating an applescript that runs the shell script?  So just open at AppleScript Editor, and enter something like this.

```
do shell script "//Your script";
```

Then save it as an application in the format drop down.

After that, you can run the script just by opening up the application with something like spotlight.